# TFS @mention name color

Tags: tfs, mention

My organization has noticed that 'mentions' sometimes appear in blue, other times in red.

What  do the different colors represent? I have not been able to find any documentation describing the differences.

Comment: I think the color is really doesn't matter any thing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the AssignedTo field, any user that has been removed from TFS is marked in red. Looking at the HTML for a field in red for the mentions has `mention-preview-me`, which is what is applying the `color: #da0a00` value. So it looks like in mentions the red is shown when you're the one being mentioned.